# How to find whether immutable ledger implementation present hyperledgerfabric samples project named fabcar

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm a beginner in hyperledger fabric. Can anyone help me to find out if the immutable ledger implementation is there or not in fabricsample project fabcar?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is there, you can use CLI to view the blocks.

Guess the [Balance Transfer](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release/balance-transfer) would be a best place for you to start than fabcar

Comment: Ok  Thanks!.But can i  use Hyperledgerexplorer instead of cli ?